# Where to call the APIs in application stack?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, web-applications, mean-stack

I'm trying to create a web application which use the APIs of some other application like "Twitter API", "Stack Exchange API" Github API. I'm thinking to use the MEAN stack for my application. As I'm new to this I'm not sure that where to call the API in the application stack.

Let me give me a example to clear my question.

Suppose I want to call the Gist API for listing the public gist in my application and display beautifully on the web browser. 
For this I have to user the GET method with the URL "https://api.github.com/gists/public". Now my question is where should I call this GET method in my application stack ?

**My requirements.**

1. Call the query from web browser using User Interface to fetch data from API provider and display on caller's browser.
2. ADD/DELETE/UPDATE from the browser itself and it should reflect on API provider website too.
3. I don't need to store any data in my application. All data will store at API provider itself. User authentication will also done via API (OAuth 2)

**I have few question on the basis of my requirements**

1. Can my requirements be achieved only from front-end (Angular.js) ? If yes, shall I still need to use server-end (Node.js) in my application ?
2. Can it be done only using server-end (Node.js) ?
3. Can you suggest some better technologies to use in my stack according to my requirements ?

I new in this area so my understanding of application stack may not be clear. So I will be very thankful if you provide some online resource to understand API call and application stack implementation . I tried to search on Google but i didn't find good one.

I found this tutorial https://zapier.com/learn/apis/ very good. But there theory only. No example is given how to use in actual code.

Please let me know if the question is not clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create services in angular to make API calls or you can call the API's on the backend (node.js app) and then use a view engine like handlebars to generate the html.